# VBA - Copy and Pasting the correct data

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble copying over various ranges into corresponding sheets.

```
dateRng = 12/19/2016 00:00:00 - 12/19/2016 23:59:59
num = 11
NumPts = 33
Sheets.Count = 16
```

In this exaple this is what each variable is equal to ^.

```
Dim dateRng As String, num As Integer, j As Integer, sh As Worksheet
dateRng = Sheets("Input Raw Data").Range("B" & counter + 2).Value
num = Sheets("Tool Setup").Range("C18").Value
NumPts = num * 3

For s = 1 To Sheets.Count
    For y = 1 To NumPts
        With Sheets(s)
        For j = 1 To num
            If .Name = j Then
                Sheets("Reporting").Range("A" & (12 * y - 7) & ":" & fConvertToLetter & (12 * y + 1)) _
                .Copy (.Range("A2"))
                .Range("A1") = dateRng
                .Name = Sheets("Point Names").Range("B" & (3 * j - 1))
            End If
            Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Next j
        End With
    Next y
Next s
```

So currently, I am getting the first range copied into the first corresponding sheet.  But it is also pasting into all the rest of the sheets afterwards.  Rather than pairing up the second range with the second sheet.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by breaking up the `For Statements` into two blocks.

```
For s = 1 To Sheets.Count
    With Sheets(s)
    For j = 1 To num
        If .Name = j Then
            .Range("A1:C1").Merge
            .Range("A1") = dateRng
            .Name = Sheets("Point Names").Range("B" & (3 * j - 1))
        End If
    Next j
    End With
Next s
For s = 1 To Sheets.Count
    With Sheets(s)
    For y = 1 To NumPts
        If .Name = Sheets("Reporting").Range("B" & (12 * y - 5)) Then
            Sheets("Reporting").Range("A" & (12 * y - 6) & _
        ":" & fConvertToLetter & (12 * y + 20)) _
        .Copy (.Range("A2"))
        .Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 12
        .Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If
    y = y + 2
    Next y
End With
Next s
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand the question. If you want to paste on different ranges through different sheets I believe you have your cycles mixed up.

Since your For j is running inside For s, you go through all the ranges in your first sheet before passing to the next sheet.

So maybe:

```
For s = 1 To Sheets.Count
For y = 1 To NumPts
    With Sheets(s)
        If .Name = s Then
            Sheets("Reporting").Range("A" & (12 * y - 7) & ":" & fConvertToLetter & (12 * y + 1)) _
            .Copy (.Range("A2"))
            .Range("A1") = dateRng
            .Name = Sheets("Point Names").Range("B" & (3 * s - 1))
        End If
        Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
Next y
Next s
```

This would only apply if I'm understanding correctly and you want your ranges to move with every next sheet.

Comment: I forgot to define `Sheets.Count = 16`, in this example. So I need the `For j` statement. I tried un-indenting the `For y` line to be even with `For s`, which produced the same outcome